# Maven 3.5 doesn't find $JAVA_HOME despite the env variable was set

Tags: java, linux, maven, ubuntu

I am trying to run Maven 3.5 on my `Ubuntu 16.04 desktop VM`. I installed `JDK 8` and set `$JAVA_HOME` and added the path. Despite this, Maven cannot find it. Here is the output:

```
root@ubuntu:/# echo $JAVA_HOME
opt/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java

root@ubuntu:/# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:opt/jdk1.8.0_131/bin:opt/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin

root@ubuntu:/# mvn -v
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly This environment variable is needed to run this program NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JAVA_HOME` should point to the JDK/JRE installation directory rather than to the `java` executable. In your case, that seems to be `/opt/jdk1.8.0_131/` (the leading `/` is important, in its absence every software will try to access an `opt` directory in its current working directory)

Then you can append `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to the `PATH`, which has correctly been done in your case but apparently does not matter to Maven.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that your maven is in a protected directory

Run using `sudo mvn -v`

Comment: For the case you are correct, would you mind to explain how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Set you path for `$JAVA_HOME` is

```
/opt/jdk1.8.0_131/
```

Absolutely Correct  path, it is the home directory for `java`. Here `1.8.0.131` is a version release to Identify the version of Java Installed.

instead of

```
opt/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java   //wrong path, it is not a home directory for java
```

> **Note** :- You may also install or put the extracted version for multiple versions of java.Version actually helps you to identify and choose right version according to need (if Needed).